# Ajax events not firing after replacing page content

Tags: ajax

After posting a reply with ajax and replacing the comments-section div with the data from the ajax response the reply-button no longer seems to fire the jQuery function

Heres my html

```
<div class="comments-section">
    <?php 
    foreach ($comments as $c)
    {?>

            <div style="margin-bottom:5px" class="comment" data-commentID="<?php echo $c->id;?>">
                <div style="border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;border:2px solid black;border-bottom-width:0px;padding:3px;font-weight:bold;">
                    <?php echo $c->user->username?>
                </div>
                <div style="border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;background-color:white;padding:5px;border:2px solid black">
                    <?php echo $c->comment;?>
                    <button class="reply-button">Reply</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
    }?>
</div>
```

And heres my jQuery function

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".reply-button").on('click',function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var reply_text = btn.siblings('.reply-text');

    if(reply_text.length) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/project/index.php/comments/postReply',
            data: {
                topic_id: '<?php echo $model->id ?>',
                comment_id: $(this).closest('.comment').attr("data-commentID"),
                comment: reply_text.val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $data = $(data);
                $('.comments-section').replaceWith($data.find('.comments-section'));
            },
        });
    } else {

        btn.before('<br><textarea style="resize:none" cols="84" rows="5" class="reply-text" placeholder="comment..."></textarea><br>');
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **Delegated events** as they have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".reply-button", function() {
// place your click event code here
});
```